# Robolectric does not launch activity in correct orientation

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm trying to have a unit test that checks whether the activity launched is in the correct orientation.
So, in my AndroidManifest.xml file, I have the orientation set as:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.xxx.MyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="target_device"
                android:value="phone" />
  </activity>
```

The tests and tested code are in the same project, so I assume Robolectric doesn't have any problems finding the manifest.
Besides, all the tests run fine except this one.

And here is my unit test:

```
ActivityController<MyActivity> activityController = Robolectric
                .buildActivity(MyActivity.class)
                .create()
                .start()
                .postCreate(null)       
                .resume()
                .visible();
        MyActivity mActivity = activityController.get();
assertEquals(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, mActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
```

The `mActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` is always 0, while portrait is 1.

Any idea why?
(using Robolectric 2.4)

Comment: Anyone find a solution to this? Generally I don't test configuration, but this seems important enough to my requirements to test. I am using Robolectric 3.0